# Typing Effect - Adding Carriage Return and Blinking Cursor

Tags: javascript

I have been using a simple typing effect script provided by [TheZillion](http://thezillion.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/javascript-typing-effect/) .

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>Typing Effect - by Zillion</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var index = 0;
            var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tincidunt, nulla at tempus tristique, nisl leo molestie est, ut vestibulum mauris mauris a odio. Sed at massa vitae ipsum venenatis porta. Integer iaculis pretium tempus. Donec viverra sollicitudin velit non gravida. Phasellus sit amet tortor odio. Vivamus lectus nisl, suscipit porttitor bibendum ut, tristique quis dui. Vestibulum non eros leo. Maecenas tincidunt semper turpis, a tristique purus pretium sit amet. Praesent nec neque tortor.Donec suscipit tristique ante quis molestie. Phasellus ac lacus non felis faucibus dictum vitae ac ipsum. Sed pharetra nulla sodales nulla porta imperdiet. Quisque pretium hendrerit laoreet.';
            // Here you can put in the text you want to make it type.
            function type() {
                document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
                index += 1;
                var t = setTimeout('type()', 100);
                // The time taken for each character here is 100ms. You can change it if you want.
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload='type()'>
        <!-- And here, you create the container in which you display the typed text -->
        <div id='screen'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to add carriage returns to the `var text` string.
Currently no `"\n", "\r",` Unicode representations or HTML tags are being recognized.

I would also like to add a blinking cursor that precedes the letters being typed in the `var text` string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code in [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/N4Fs9/)

Comment: Either change the output tag to be a `<pre>` and use `\n`, or continue with a `<div>` and use `<br />` instead

Comment: @Ian: Only that the `<br>` element won't work with this naive implementation. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13391131/1048572 for the problem

Comment: @Bergi Good point. Great solution :)

Comment: Try [typed.js](https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/). Though I never tried it, they support HTML tags and blinking cursor which can help you to achieve carriage return effect. If HTML tags are not required then you can try [shabdawali](https://github.com/amitguptagwl/shabdawali) for more effects.